# RethinkDB: does reduce iterate all grouped data?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I thought I had it with rethinkdb :) but now I'm a bit confused -
for this query, counting grouped data:

```
groupedRql.count()
```

I'm getting the expected results (numbers):

```
[{"group": "a", "reduction": 41}, {"group": "b", "reduction": 39}...]
```

all reduction results are ~40 which is expected (and correct), but when I count using reduce like this:

```
groupedRql.map(function(row) {
  return row.merge({
    count: 0
  })
}).reduce(function(left, right) {
  return {count: left("count").add(1)}
})
```

I'm getting much lower results (~10) which MAKE NO SENSE:

```
[{"group": "a", "reduction": 10}, {"group": "b", "reduction": 9}...]
```

I need to use reduce, of course, for further manipulation.
Am I missing something?

I'm using v2.0.3 on server, queries tested directly on the dataexplorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lay in here

```
return {count: left("count").add(1)}
```

It should be

```
return {count: left("count").add(right("count"))}
```

The reduce run paralel between multiple shards, multiple CPU core. When you do

```
return {count: left("count").add(1)}
```

you ignore some count from the `right`.

It's noted in this document: https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/map-reduce/#how-gmr-queries-are-executed

> it’s important to keep in mind that the reduce function is not called
>   on the elements of its input stream from left to right. It’s called on
>   either the elements of the stream in any order or on the output of
>   previous calls to the function.

Comment: In this case then, 'count' should be initialized to 1

Comment: which also means, 'count' should be subtracted by 1 eventually?